# Invalid Procedure Call or Argument (Error 5) when calling User32 PostMessage

Tags: vba, postmessage, user32

The following code returns "Run-Time Error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument" at the line:

result = PostMessage(h, WM_CHAR, Asc(Mid$(vbCr, i, 1)), 0&)

```
Private Const WM_CHAR = &H102
Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Sub PostToCmdLine()
    Dim h As Long
    Dim result As Boolean
    ' find dos prompt window
    h = FindWindow(vbNullString, "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe")
    Stop
    If h Then
        ' send "calc.exe" followed by carraige return
        result = PostMessage(h, WM_CHAR, Asc(Mid$(vbCr, i, 1)), 0&)
        ' optional, check postmessage result
        If result = False Then MsgBox ("postmessage failed!")
        'close the hidden dos prompt window
        ' SendTxt(h, "exit" & vbCr)
    Else
        MsgBox ("dos prompt window not found")
    End If
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This never even makes the call to `PostMessage` - the error is in this bit:

```
Asc(Mid$(vbCr, i, 1))
```

The variable `i` is never declared or assigned a value (and is a great argument for adding `Option Explicit` to all your modules...) so it is trying to read `Mid$` from position 0.  It's 1 based, thus your error.

That said, it isn't clear why you're trying to extract 1 character from a 1 character long literal.  `Asc(Mid$(vbCr, i, 1))` is the same as `Asc(vbCr)` which is *always* `13`.  Just use this:

```
result = PostMessage(h, WM_CHAR, 13&, 0&)
```

Note that this doesn't match your comment of "send "calc.exe" followed by carraige return" at all.  In order to do that with `WM_CHAR` messages, you need to post all of the individual characters. Just skip the `Asc` and `Mid$` entirely by treating the string as a byte array:

```
Dim chars() As Byte
chars = StrConv("calc.exe" & vbCr, vbFromUnicode)
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(chars) To UBound(chars)
    result = PostMessage(h, WM_CHAR, CLng(chars(i)), 0&)
    'Check result to see if you need to bail here.
Next
```